# Returning dataframe from function is not working?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create the following function. However, when I assign the function to the original dataframe, it becomes empty.

```
def remove_outliers(feature, df):
    q1 = np.percentile(df[feature], 25) 
    q2 = np.percentile(df[feature], 50) 
    q3 = np.percentile(df[feature], 75) 

    iqr = q3-q1    
    lower_whisker = df[df[feature] <= q1-1.5*iqr][feature].max()
    upper_whisker = df[df[feature] <= q3+1.5*iqr][feature].max()

    return  df[(df[feature] < upper_whisker) & (df[feature]>lower_whisker)]
```

I am assigning as follows:

```
train = remove_outliers('Power',train)
```

Comment: I believe your issue is that your varibles `lower_whisker` and/or `upper_whisker` are set to `NaN` hence the result from the function is an empty DataFrame

Comment: Yeah as Cedric pointed out, either `df[df[feature] <= q1-1.5*iqr][feature]` or `df[df[feature] <= q3+1.5*iqr][feature]` is coming out as an empty dataframe causing your output to return a empty dataframe

Comment: Actually those variables I pointed out are meant to be numbers. And once those are set to `NaN` then the result is an emtpy DataFrame

Comment: The issue @Chaos_Adm is having is dependant on the data. If the data has values lower than 25 and higher than 75 no issues would arise from the OP code.

Comment: Since I am working between percentile ranges, how can there be any empty dataset generation?

Comment: Okay my condition for lower_whisker was wrong lol. It should be `train[train['Power'] >= q1-1.5*iqr]['Power'].min()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that either variable `lower_whisker` and/or `upper_whisker` are set to `NaN` hence the result from the function is an empty DataFrame. You can resolve this just checking for those results and then return the needed.

Below you can see a possible way to rewrite the function to resolve this:

```
def remove_outliers(feature, df):
    q1 = np.percentile(df[feature], 25)
    q2 = np.percentile(df[feature], 50)
    q3 = np.percentile(df[feature], 75)

    iqr = q3-q1
    lower_whisker = df[df[feature] <= q1-1.5*iqr][feature].max()
    upper_whisker = df[df[feature] <= q3+1.5*iqr][feature].max()
    if lower_whisker is np.nan:
        return df[(df[feature]>lower_whisker)]
    elif upper_whisker is np.nan:
        return df[(df[feature] < upper_whisker)]
    else:
        return df[(df[feature] < upper_whisker) & (df[feature]>lower_whisker)]
```

Comment: How can they be set to NaN? There must be a lot of data points within the 25th and 75th percentile of data, unless I am missing something here?

Comment: Okay my condition for lower_whisker was wrong lol. It should be `train[train['Power'] >= q1-1.5*iqr]['Power'].min()`